# Best practice to backup /etc config files

Tags: ubuntu, backup, remote-management

I want to setup [froxlor](http://www.froxlor.org/) on not fresh install remote server (Ubuntu 10.04.2).

I take care  of admin the server since two month. Before I start, the previous guy installed and config some services and files. I don't know what he exactly does, I can only view what he installed (by the history) but not what he edit.
I want to install the Server-Management-Panel 'Froxlor' to administrate the whole stuff with it and not doing it manually by ssh. My cousin (he rent the server) should also be able to config some stuff with the browser.

These services already installed and configured and used

- apache 2 + php 5 + mysql 5.1
- proftp 1.3
- postfix 2.7 + courier 0.62

The tutorials I found, are based on fresh install system. I already installed froxlor, but for using it I have to execute some scripts and change/overwrite the config files of the services. But if I do it, the current configurations will be lost.

**What's the best practice to backup the configs as simple as possible** (with less effort and problems) and configure froxlor and then merge the backuped files.

Which data / config files I have to backup?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install [etckeeper](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/etckeeper/). On Ubuntu, that's the [etckeeper package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/etckeeper) [image: Install etckeeper]. Choose your favorite version control system (amongst Bazaar, Darcs, Git and Mercury). Run `etckeeper init`.

Now, every time you modify a configuration file, run `sudo bzr commit` from `/etc` (or `sudo git commit` or whatever). Also, every time you install, upgrade or remove a package, changes in `/etc` will be automatically committed to version control (with a generic message, so it's best to commit manually with a meaningful message). To revert to an earlier version, use `bzr revert` (or …).

Answer (score 0):

for apache most config files will be located in /etc/apache2 . 
Proftpd config files are also placed in /etc (/etc/proftpd). 
Postfix configuration files can be found in /etc/postfix and courier in /etc/courier.

Best thing u should do is create a tar of all these files (tar cvzfp /root/apache2.tar.gz /etc/apache2 and so on). Use the p parameter to preserve the permissions of the files.