# Logging and controlling changes to the system

Tags: version-control

I am looking for an advice on a very lightweight local server or option for version of control of system administration changes.

We have few secure Ubuntu servers that are not on the network, but we want to track changes to the configuration and the modifications to the installed packages (e.g. install MongoDB, modify its configuration).

Does anyone have any recommendation for an agile, lightweight tool and approach to version control?

Comment: `etckeeper` should do most of what you are looking for.

Comment: What unix variant is it? What kind of tracking do you want to do: is this about monitoring what clueless admins might do, or keeping track of normal changes? If the latter and it's available on your unix variant, I second the etckeeper recommendation; see [How to keep track of changes in /etc/](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29117/how-to-keep-track-of-changes-in-etc)

Comment: It for Ubuntu Server and it is about tracking the changes to the system configurations as well as changes to the configurations of the system wide, third party packages such as MongoDB, postgres, nginx. Hope this helps.