# Get diff changes between original files installed with apt and current files

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt, diff

I installed `php5-fpm` package using `apt`; then I made some changes to the PHP configuration files.

Now I would get the diffs between the original files versions (the ones of the package installed) and the current versions (modified by me). How to do it?

Comment: It is hard to understand what exactly you want to know. It is not even clear what your situation is.

Comment: I don't know if apt can tell you that, but what I do recommend is to put `/etc` under revision control (I use mercurial for that) and `add` and `commit` on a regular basis. That way you can roll back to original files, or to intermediate changed states and with `hg diff` you can see changes. If you cannot find a way to do this with `apt`, backup your changed files, reinstall the packag(es), bring the config files under revision control and copy back your changes. After that you can do a diff.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I am not good at english, I'm sorry

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/10997/find-what-package-a-file-belongs-to-in-ubuntu-debian

Comment: @reinierpost no it isn't. I want the diffs.

Comment: Once you can retrieve the original, you can create the diffs with `diff`.

Comment: I linked to the wrong question! Related questions to this one are http://superuser.com/questions/315722/ubuntu-compare-original-package-and-installed-parameters and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16917/best-practice-to-backup-config-files#17047

Comment: @Anthon Please use `etckeeper` instead of some "manual" approach (or at least _recommend_ it over the manual approach). It deals with some of the idiosyncrasies of `/etc` out of the box and supports several version control systems, including Mercurial.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
# exit on failure
set -e

package=php5-fpm
mkdir $package
cd $package

# you could also get the file from a package mirror if you have
#  an older version of apt-get that doesn't support 'download' 
#  or if you would like more control over what package version
#  you are downloading.
# (e.g. http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/)
apt-get download $package

# deb package files are ar archives
ar vx ${package}*.deb
# containing some compressed tar archives
tar xzf data.tar.gz
# now you have the files

# you can get diffs for all of the files in etc if you would like
find etc -type f |
while read file ; do
    diff $file /$file
done
```

As suggested by others, definitely put your configuration files under revision control. That way, you can see exactly what you changed and when you changed it.

Comment: Thank you! I had to modify a bit the code: https://gist.github.com/ProGNOMmers/5404609 if you update your question with working code I will be happy to accept it

Comment: I'm glad my solution worked for you. I have included your changes and fixes in my code.

Comment: `tar xzf data.tar.gz` should be `tar xf data.tar.xz` for recent Ubuntu

Comment: You could use `dpkg-deb -x ${package}_*.deb .` instead of using `ar` and `tar`. Also `apt-get download $(dpkg-query -W -f='${binary:Package}=${Version}' $package)` will make sure you grab the currently installed version rather than the latest, for example if you are doing this just before doing an upgrade.

Comment: I fixed an error where there is no data.tar.gz but `data.tar.xz` https://github.com/rubo77/apt-etc-diff - also enhanced the script a bit

Comment: This does not work for packages like `php`, where the initial etc file `php.ini` is generated on install and not directly contained in the packages. How would you solve it for those?

Comment: @rubo77 I have a Dockerfile that I build with just the package(s) from which I need the untainted configuration files. build and initiate with a directory mapped in to /tmp, and then copy the config file to /tmp within the running container. That should work for PHP as well.

Answer (score 10):

#### etc directory

For tracking changes to your `/etc` directory you can do as @Anthon has suggested and use git, subversion, mercurial, etc. to version control that directory. You can also use a tool such as [etckeeper](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/etckeeper.html). There's a tutorial [here](http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/keep-configs-under-control-with-etckeeper.html) as well as [here](https://github.com/joeyh/etckeeper).

> etckeeper is a collection of tools to let /etc be stored in a git,
>   mercurial, bazaar or darcs repository. It hooks into apt to
>   automatically commit changes made to /etc during package upgrades. It
>   tracks file metadata that git does not normally support, but that is
>   important for /etc, such as the permissions of `/etc/shadow`. It's
>   quite modular and configurable, while also being simple to use if you
>   understand the basics of working with version control.

#### package files

To my knowledge `apt` does not have a way to check the files on disk vs. the files that are in the actual `.deb`. Neither does `dpkg`, the tool that `apt` is actually using to do the management of files.

However you can use a tool such as [`debsums`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/debsums.1.html) to compare some of the files you have installed, it only looks at their checksums (md5sum) of what's in the `.deb` file vs. what's on your systems disk.

See this [serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/322518/can-dpkg-verify-files-from-an-installed-package) for more details about `debsum` and `dpkg` checksumming, as well as this [askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9463/what-is-the-apt-equivalent-to-rpm-v-verify-installed-packages).

#### `debsum` example

```
% debsums openssh-server
/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server                                                  OK
/usr/sbin/sshd                                                                OK
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/openssh-server                                   OK
/usr/share/man/man5/sshd_config.5.gz                                          OK
/usr/share/man/man8/sshd.8.gz                                                 OK
/usr/share/man/man8/sftp-server.8.gz                                          OK
```

Comment: thank you a lot! I didn't know about the practice to keep `/etc` under revision control, and `etckeeper` seems the right solution in order to manage it; I will adopt it

Comment: Note that the OP will need to run `debsums -a`, otherwise configuration files will be excluded from the check.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev `debums -ce` is perfect to find which (configuration) files to look at.

Comment: List all the modified configuration files of installed packages: dpkg -l | grep -E '^ii' | awk '{print $2}' | sudo xargs debsums -se

Answer (score 10):

I wrote the following simple script to automatically retrieve the original file from the right Debian package and diff the current file against it: https://a3nm.net/git/mybin/tree/debdiffconf

Use it as follows: `debdiffconf FILE`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Usage: debdiffconf.sh FILE
# Produce on stdout diff of FILE against the first installed Debian package
# found that provides it.
# Returns the exit code of diff if everything worked, 3 or 4 otherwise.

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/4785518
command -v apt >/dev/null 2>&1 || {
  echo "apt not found, this is probably not a Debian system. Aborting." >&2;
  exit 4; }
command -v apt-file >/dev/null 2>&1 || {
  echo "Please install apt-file: sudo apt install apt-file. Aborting." >&2;
  exit 4; }
command -v realpath >/dev/null 2>&1 || {
  echo "Please install realpath: sudo apt install realpath. Aborting." >&2;
  exit 4; }

FILE=$(realpath -m "$1")
while read PACKAGE
do
  # verify from first installed package
  if dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Status}\n' | grep installed > /dev/null
  then
    DIR=$(mktemp -d)
    cd "$DIR"
    echo "Trying $PACKAGE..." >&2
    apt download "$PACKAGE" >&2
    # downloaded archive is the only file present...
    ARCHIVE=$(ls)
    mkdir contents
    # extract entire archive
    dpkg-deb -x "$ARCHIVE" contents/ >&2
    if [ -f "contents$FILE" ]
    then
      # package contained required file
      diff "contents$FILE" "$FILE"
      RET=$?
      # cleanup
      cd
      rm -Rf "$DIR"
      # exit entire script as this is the main shell
      # with the return code from diff
      exit $RET
    else
      # cleanup
      cd
      rm -Rf "$DIR"
    fi
  fi
done < <(apt-file -l search "$FILE")
# if we are here, it means we have found no suitable package
echo "Could not find original package for $FILE" >&2
exit 3
```

Comment: Your script also requires `realpath` package installed.

Comment: @Mxx: thanks, adding a check for this package, although starting with Debian jessie it seems that coreutils is providing a `realpath' command.

Comment: It was missing on Ubuntu.

Comment: [Here](https://www.win.tue.nl/~rp/bin/dpkgdiff) is mine.

Comment: @reinierpost - that should say "Here was mine" ;}  Your link gives a 404 ...

Comment: Aargh ... thanks, it is [here](http://www.win.tue.nl/~rp/dpkg-bin/dpkgdiff) now.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works for packages that come from repositories with a Contents file. Otherwise, excellent script!

Comment: For archived debian versions, you need to add `echo "Acquire::Check-Valid-Until false;" | tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10-nocheckvalid` and then `apt-get install apt-file realpath`

Comment: Would `dpkg --search` work where you use apt-file?

Comment: @Clément: I'm not sure, that's possible -- it would also look only in installed packages, which I agree could be preferable

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the differences between original and the installed `php.ini` file, use

```
diff -W COLUMNS --suppress-common-lines -y /usr/share/php5/php.ini-development /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini -W $COLUMNS
```

if you don't care about the comment lines pipe it into

```
| egrep -v '^;.*<$|\s*>.;.*|;.*\|.;'
```

Comment: The problem is less about how to invoking diff and more about how to compare a file that has been modified with the original version (as it was installed by the package manager). If there was 2 files to start with, that would be easy indeed.

Comment: The location of the files may differ per platform; I found them in  `/usr/lib/php/<version>/php.ini-production.cli` and `/etc/php/<version>/cli/php.ini` f.i.