# How to verify that package-installed files match originals?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, integrity

Let's say I have an installed, working and up-to-date system, and want to verify that all package-installed files on it are the same as those packaged by the respective package maintainer.

In effect, I want *a list of files that are somehow different between what I have installed "now" and what I would get if I were to reinstall using the same set of packages on a blank system.* Short of actually reinstalling and comparing the outcome, **how would I generate such a list of files?**

I realize that some differences (configuration files, for example) are to be expected, but that's okay.

I'm primarily interested in Debian Wheezy, but a good answer would explore a solution that works with any reasonably modern Linux distribution based around the same package management infrastructure (apt, dpkg and friends).

Comment: Possibly related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72746/get-diff-changes-between-original-files-installed-with-apt-and-current-files

Comment: @slm http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72778/2465 does have something that I could probably adapt, too. Thanks for that pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to use the command `debsums`.

```
$ debsums <package>
```

#### Example

```
$ debsums xz-utils
/usr/bin/lzmainfo                                                             OK
/usr/bin/xz                                                                   OK
/usr/bin/xzdiff                                                               OK
/usr/bin/xzgrep                                                               OK
/usr/bin/xzless                                                               OK
/usr/bin/xzmore                                                               OK
/usr/share/doc/xz-utils/NEWS.Debian.gz                                        OK
/usr/share/doc/xz-utils/README.Debian                                         OK
/usr/share/doc/xz-utils/README.gz                                             OK
/usr/share/doc/xz-utils/copyright                                             OK
/usr/share/doc/xz-utils/extra/7z2lzma/7z2lzma.bash                            OK
/usr/share/doc/xz-utils/extra/scanlzma/scanlzma.c                             OK
/usr/share/doc/xz-utils/faq.txt.gz                                            OK
/usr/share/doc/xz-utils/history.txt.gz                                        OK
/usr/share/man/man1/lzmainfo.1.gz                                             OK
/usr/share/man/man1/xz.1.gz                                                   OK
/usr/share/man/man1/xzdiff.1.gz                                               OK
/usr/share/man/man1/xzgrep.1.gz                                               OK
/usr/share/man/man1/xzless.1.gz                                               OK
/usr/share/man/man1/xzmore.1.gz                                               OK
```

Comment: Not precisely what I was hoping for because [not all files actually have stored checksums](http://serverfault.com/a/322554/58408), but this does seem to get me reasonably close at least: `dpkg -l | awk '/^ii/ { print $2 }' | xargs debsums | grep -vE 'OK$'` It's worth noting that debsums reads locally stored checksums; that is not a problem if you're only concerned about accidental corruption, but potentially a problem if you're concerned about an active, intelligent attacker.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - I did not research further but would be very surprised if `dpkg` didn't offer a facility to do this too. In my cursory searches I did not turn up anything though. RPM does offer a check and as is the case both RPM and `dpkg` generally are on par with each other.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
dpkg -V <package>
```

I test it and it works also on configuraton files.

After modifying `/etc/iceweasel/profile/bookmarks.html` and running `dpkg -V iceweasel`, I obtain the following output

```
??5?????? c /etc/iceweasel/profile/bookmarks.html
```

Note that only modified files are displayed and according to the [dpkg man page](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dpkg&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+testing+jessie&format=html&locale=en), the output format is similar to `rpm`.