# How to securely verify that package-installed files match originals (Debian)?

Tags: security, dpkg, debian-installer

From the question [How to verify that package-installed files match originals?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/133889/how-to-verify-that-package-installed-files-match-originals?newreg=3898da5c2ebc499f931567a5505c95e8) I understand that you can run the following command for a package:

```
dpkg -V <package>
```

The reason why I am carrying out this audit is, however, because I somehow suspect that the system could be compromised.

If the attacker has managed to subvert <package>, he could also have managed to subvert the **dpkg** audit command itself. Therefore, I cannot trust the self-referential audit:

```
dpkg -V dpkg
```

Therefore, I want to run the self-audit of the **dpkg** command from another system.

So, I mount the disk of this computer as folder **/mnt/audit** in my second computer, which I still trust. Now, I want to audit the installation foot print of **dpkg** in **/mnt/audit** from this second computer. What command do execute on my second computer? Is there an option that allows me to do something similar to the following:

```
dpkg -V dpkg --remote-target /mnt/audit
```

Once I trust the self-audit of **dpkg**, I should be able to trust its output for <package> as well.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, if you suspect that your system has been compromised, you should re-install it. See [Process with weird random name consuming significant network and CPU resources. Is someone hacking me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/428721/86440) for some useful pointers.

`dpkg -V` is useful to detect accidental corruption. It relies on local metadata (`.md5sum` files in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`), so on a compromised system, there’s no guarantee that this metadata is still accurate. If you want to verify your system externally, you could download all the corresponding packages and check the sums the system you’re checking against those of the packages, or even re-install all the packages; but that would still leave you exposed — in particular, package metadata doesn’t cover the boot loader and the initramfs.

To address your actual question, `dpkg` can be run against user-specified directories; for example, to check `/mnt/audit` while assuming that its contents are mostly trustworthy, run

```
dpkg --root=/mnt/audit -V dpkg
```

The administrative and installation directories can be distinguished, so if your auditing system has the same package versions as the audited system, you could run

```
dpkg --instdir=/mnt/audit -V dpkg
```

to verify the audited system’s `dpkg` using the auditing system’s metadata.