# Ways to identify config file modifications and show diffs?

Tags: debian, centos, configuration

Is there a practical way to identify and diff, after the fact, which config file modifications (i.e. files under `/etc/`) have been modified, i.e. are different to the defaults?

(Asking primarily for Debian and Centos, but answers for other Linux flavours are also welcome.)

Comment: `etckeeper` but needs to be installed before changes. It will keep a record of all changes. It uses your favourite revision control system, so allows diffs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `debsums` for finding changes in general or use a diff-script provided here: [Get diff changes between original files installed with apt and current files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72746/get-diff-changes-between-original-files-installed-with-apt-and-current-files)

Comment: `debsums` won’t work for the vast majority of files in `/etc`, they’re not covered by the checksum files provided by the packages. However the solution given in your link is useful for Debian.